# Linux Kernel routing on same subnet packets

Tags: linux, routes, kernel, subnet

I'm looking for an handler or something else in Linux Kernel (v 3.10) to check if there is some kind of option enabled that allows the kernel to make routing on packets from the same subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I found a possible solution browsing through handlers in the following path:
*/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/**
Setting to 0 */proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/accept_redirects* could fix my problem.

```
echo 0 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/accept_redirects
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

It specifies whether the kernel performs IPv4 packet routing or not.

Comment: Correct, but I need something more specific. The kernel I'm studying seems to perform routing on packets from the **same subnet**. This is something very strange so I'm trying to understand if there is some option related to this issue.

Comment: This variable keep status of forwarding packets in the kernel. Routing means participating in routing using routing algorithms such as `OSPF`.